# handleSubmit not accessing the value from input

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a simple spreadsheet that will calculate certain values. I am using react and have two input values that will be taken into consideration. I want it to be displayed on submit but when I press submit it doesn't seem to get the values and it doesn't display anything.

```
export default class name extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
     value: '',
     calls: ''
   };
this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

   handleInputChange(event) {
     const target = event.target;
     const value = target.name;
     const calls = target.name;


this.setState({
  value: value,
  calls: value,
  });
event.preventDefault();
 }


 handleSubmit(event) {
   document.getElementById("subsmonth").innerHTML = this.state.value * 10;
    document.getElementById("usecost").innerHTML = this.state.calls * 0.03;
    document.getElementById("monthCost").innerHTML = (this.state.calls * 0.03) + (this.state.value * 10);
    document.getElementById("yearCost").innerHTML = ((this.state.calls * 0.03) + (this.state.value * 10) * 12);
   event.preventDefault();

 }

  render() {
    return (

<div className="cl-product cl-full-width">
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <label>
           Phone users:
           <input type="number" name="users" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
         </label>
         <label>
           Total calls per month:
           <input type="number" name="calls" value={this.state.calls} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
         </label>
         <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
       </form>
  <p> Subscriptions per month</p>
  <div id="subsmonth"></div>
  <p>Usage costs per month* - *Excluding calls to 08 numbers (at 10ppm)</p>
  <div id="usecost"></div>
  <p> Monthly Cost</p>
  <div id="monthCost"></div>
  <p>Annual Cost</p>
  <div id="yearCost"></div>


</div>
    )
  }
}
```

How do I make this recognise the input value and display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the working code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: '',
          calls: ''
        };
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        let obj = {};
        obj[target.name] = target.value;

        this.setState(obj);
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    handleSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("subsmonth").innerHTML = this.state.value * 10;
        document.getElementById("usecost").innerHTML = this.state.calls * 0.03;
        document.getElementById("monthCost").innerHTML = (this.state.calls * 0.03) + (this.state.value * 10);
        document.getElementById("yearCost").innerHTML = ((this.state.calls * 0.03) + (this.state.value * 10) * 12);   
    }

    render() {
        return (
         <div className="cl-product cl-full-width">
             <label>
                 Phone users:
                 <input type="number" name="value" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
              </label>
              <br/>
              <label>
                 Total calls per month:
                 <input type="number" name="calls" value={this.state.calls} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
              </label>
              <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
        <p> Subscriptions per month</p>
        <div id="subsmonth"></div>
        <p>Usage costs per month* - *Excluding calls to 08 numbers (at 10ppm)</p>
        <div id="usecost"></div>
        <p> Monthly Cost</p>
        <div id="monthCost"></div>
        <p>Annual Cost</p>
        <div id="yearCost"></div>
         </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='app'/>
```